# Why can't read deduce the correct type?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

In Haskell, I can make Haskell value from a string with `read`.

```
Prelude> read "1" + 3
4
```

I can use `fst` to get the first element

```
Prelude> fst (1,2)
1
```

However, I get an error when I combine `read` and `fst` to get the first element:

```
Prelude> fst (read "(1,2)")

<interactive>:20:6:
    Could not deduce (Read b0) arising from a use of ‘read’
    from the context (Read a)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Read a => a
      at <interactive>:20:1-18
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `read` is a polymorphic function, the `read "3" + 4` works because the compiler know you want a `Num` because you applied `+` to `read "3"`, If the compiler can't figure out what you want, you have to specify type of `read`, like this:

```
Prelude> let rd = read :: String->(Int,Int)
Prelude> rd "(1,2)"
```

Comment: Detail: you have to specify the type as long as nothing else does it for you (cf. the first example in the question, which works fine).

Comment: The first example only works because of numeric defaulting.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the type signature of `read`:

```
Prelude> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

As you can see, its return value must have a type of the `Read` typeclass. However, if we don't use the value the complier won't know what type it is.

In such cases, we can add `::` to specify its type.

```
Prelude> read "5"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
Prelude> read "5" :: Int
5
```

Similarly,

```
Prelude> read "(1, 2)"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
Prelude> read "(1, 2)" :: (Int, Int)
(1,2)
Prelude> fst (read "(1,2)" :: (Int, Int))
1
```

The compiler can deduce the types most of the time, but when it meets `read "5"`, it may get confused about whether the type should be `Int` or `Float` or anything else. Only after computing, Haskell can know its type. On the other hand, Haskell has static types, so **it has to know all type before compiling**.

Comment: By "Only after computing, Haskell can know its type", do you mean that you need to use the value so that the compiler can figure out the type?